Trade start on raydium
Is there any way to know when the trade of a token starts? Raydium provides webhooks to listen for newly added tokens, but some tokens set a specific time for when trading will open. These webhooks can notify us of these tokens as well. Is there a way to know that a token's trading will open in 1 hour, 5 hours, etc., and automatically buy the token after this time?
